# @Component annotation is unresolved

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, ant

[Here's a screenshot of my IntelliJ Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsRSp.jpg)
I'm using IntelliJIdea 15.0.2 on a Windows OS and an Ant-Build project.
I get the "Cannot resolve symbol 'Component' " error when trying to use it the following way:

```
@Component
public class StreamGateway {
}
```

There is no hint of any library that I would import by hitting Alt+Enter.
If I try to manually import :

`import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;`

I get a  404 error when trying to download some libraries by the "Find jar on web" option. I've also tried to manually download "data-management-cli-1.2.3.1-app.jar" but can't find it.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't use any dependency management system like Maven or Ivy, you have to download the needed libraries by yourself and add them manually to your project (i would strongly recommend to use a build system which manages the dependencies itself).

However, in your case you need the Spring Framework, but AFAIK they don't provide a zipped distribution any more. So you have to download the JARs from Maven central (http://search.maven.org). Put them in a folder in your project and add them as Project Library in IntelliJ.

Comment: I found out that I had all those libraries already, but didn't add them in my Project Structure as Libraries.Thanks for the advice, I will give Maven a try at some point.